# Regexp to match "START ... END" blocks

Tags: java, regex

How to write a regexp to match such groups(in JAVA):

```
START s1 8 a  

a a b ebd 

END


START any character END

START END
```

I have tried:

```
START(.*)END

final Matcher matcher = Pattern.compile("START(.*)END").matcher(versions);
```

But multi lines START END blocks aren't being matched.

Comment: What is the programming language you are using? You need to add some flag that mentions that `.` should also match new lines.

Comment: In which environment are you doing this? Bash, Python, Perl, ...?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Make the seach not greedy:

```
START(.*?)END
```

and don't forget the flag `Pattern.DOTALL`

Answer (score 1):

In your pattern, you should specify a flag that makes `.` also match new lines:

```
Pattern.compile("START(.*?)END", Pattern.DOTALL);
```

**Edit:** Also, as Carlos pointed out in the comments, you also should make your regex not greedy (replace `.*` by `.*?`).

Comment: `.*` is greedy, that is, will try to match as much as possible, in this case up to the **last** `END, probably the whole input

Comment: Right, answer updated.

Comment: It isn't specified in the question, but I would also add a warning about the fact that nested START...END blocks can't be properly matched by regular expressions.